# C# using fiddlercore to create an auto response to a url

Tags: c#, http, fiddler, auto-responder

Using the application "Fiddler", I can save a HTTP raw response as a text file. Then using the "AutoResponder" tab I can do something like this:

```
URI: http://www.request.com/file.php
File: c:\raw_response.txt
```

And my application will connect to "http://www.request.com/file.php" and always get that file.

I want to do that, but not using fiddler. I want to do this via a C# application either using the fiddler core, or just pure C# (if possible I would prefer this).

I have looked at the fiddler API and docs but it is not very clear, and it seems to be all over the place.

Comment: Hi, i was wondering if you can share the solution with me, cus i have the same problem and i couldnt figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out after contacting fiddler they said its not possible with how I want to do this. I would need the fiddler application it self.